# Grab Microsoft Edge Tab title/URL using Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I'm brand new to Powershell.

I'm writing a script to validate the basic functionality of Microsoft Edge. All it needs to do is open an msedge window and check to see that the correct default site loads.

I originally wanted to grab the URL and output it but I only see solutions that are way too lengthy for a script like this, so I opted to output the result of grabbing `MainWindowTitle`.

I am trying to use it like this:

```
if((Get-Process | Select MainWindowTitle) -like "wikipedia.org"){
  Write-Host "Site successfully opened."
} else {
  Write-Host "Site failed."
}
```

Despite landing on the correct site and the output of `Get-Process | Select MainWindowTitle` being identical to the string I compare it to, the test fails. The command works fine outside of an if statement so I guess it can't be used in the way I'm attempting to use it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select MainWindowTitle` outputs an **object** with a single property.

Comparing an object with a string usually doesn't work as expected (PowerShell tries to convert the object to string using its `.ToString()` method, which in case of a process object produces something like "System.Diagnostics.Process (*processname*)").

You may use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3) in its simplified form to filter for objects with given property values:

```bash
if( Get-Process | Where-Object MainWindowTitle -like '*wikipedia.org*' ) {
  Write-Host "Site successfully opened."
} else {
  Write-Host "Site failed."
}
```

The condition evaluates to `$true`, if `Where-Object` found at least one matching process object.

Comment: Oh awesome that makes a lot of sense now. This worked. Thanks a lot!